# Variable addition is being ignored within a method

Tags: c#, function, procedures

The premise is moving a character around a grid based upon their choice of direction and the value of a dice roll.

The function `CalculateMove` is being called within `PrepareMove`. Within CalculateMove the variable `finishX` or `finishY` are added or subtracted by the value of `diceValue`.

Everything to do with finalX or finalY within CalculateMove is being ignored, even when writing += 3 outside an if statement. 
[The screenshot of a little debug log shows that the variables finishX, finishY and foo are not being treated in the method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwzn2.png)

```
static void PrepareMove(Position startPosition, Position finishPosition, Player playerGreen, Player playerYellow, Player playerBlue, Player playerRed, string playerMoveDirection, string currentPlayer, string winningPlayer, string[,] board, int diceValue, int startX, int startY, int finishX, int finishY, bool gameOver)
    {            
        GetStartPosition(board, startPosition, currentPlayer, startX, startY);            
        CalculateMove(playerMoveDirection, board, diceValue, startX, startY, finishX, finishY);
        Console.WriteLine("\nStart XY = " + startX + "-" + startY + "\nDice Value = " + diceValue + "\nMoveDir = " + playerMoveDirection + "\nFinish XY = " + finishX + " -- " + finishY + "\n"); 
        CheckPieceCaptured(board, playerGreen, playerYellow, playerBlue, playerRed, currentPlayer, winningPlayer, finishX, finishY, gameOver); 
        MakeMove(board, startX, startY, finishX, finishY); 
    }

    static void CalculateMove(string playerMoveDirection, string[,] board, int diceValue, int startX, int startY, int finishX, int finishY)
    {
        finishX += 3; 
        if (playerMoveDirection.ToUpper().Equals("UP"))
        {
            finishX = startX;
            finishY = startY - diceValue;
        }
        else if (playerMoveDirection.ToUpper().Equals("DOWN"))
        {
            finishX = startX;
            finishY = startY + diceValue;
        }
        else if (playerMoveDirection.ToUpper().Equals("LEFT"))
        {
            finishX = startX - diceValue;
            finishY = startY;
        }
        else if (playerMoveDirection.ToUpper().Equals("RIGHT"))
        {
            finishX = startX + diceValue;
            finishY = startY; 
        }
    }
```

any ideas guys? :( 
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Your are passing `finishX` and `finishY` by value, so when you change their values inside the `CalculateMove` method, you are changing the value of a copy that is local to `CalculateMove` method, not the original variable.

You need to pass `finishX` and `finishY` by reference like this:

```
static void CalculateMove(
    string playerMoveDirection,
    string[,] board,
    int diceValue, int startX, int startY,
    ref int finishX, ref int finishY)
{
    ...
}
```

You also need to do the same thing for the `PrepareMove` method.

By the way, it would be better if you create a class to hold your X and Y values like this:

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

And then have the following definition of the method:

```
static void CalculateMove(
    string playerMoveDirection,
    string[,] board,
    int diceValue,
    Coordinates start_coordinates,
    Coordinates finish_coordinates)
{
    ...
}
```

And then you can access the coordinates like this:

```
finish_coordinates.X = ...
```

This will make your code more readable and you won't have to pass it by reference.

You should also do the same for the other methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "ref int finishX" and "ref int finishY" for your parameters to retain values, after function exits.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx